# Вывести количество цифр после запятой c++

Tags: c++

Необходимо вывести количество символов после запятой на C++.
Пример: ввёл число 1.324234. Получил: 6 знаков после запятой.
Ввёл 1.1. 1 знай после запятой.

Как такое сделать?

Comment: невозможно: в приведённых вами строках нет запятой.

Comment: Да, вполне возможно. Начинайте.

Comment: Сомнительно в общем случае. Проблема в том, что одна и та же дробь может иметь конечную десятичную запись, но бесконечную двоичную. Да, наоборот не бывает, а хранится число в виде конечной двоичной дроби. Вот только при переводе в десятичную систему приходится считать в двоичной, переводя обратно в двоичную систему промежуточные результаты перевода в десятичную, из-за чего можно упереться в бесконечность на ровном месте. И кому Вы приказываете знать первого?

Comment: @ТарасАтавин, это обычная проблема ошибок округления. Нет никаких принципиальных проблем, если с точностью до ошибок округления 6 знаков, значит 6 знаков. Надо только это дело аккуратно формализовать.

Comment: А где у меня хоть слово о строгом доказательстве нерешаемости задачи? Причём, частный случай – это вовсе не конкретное значение.

Comment: Введено 0,25. Это два знака. Как-то записали это число как 1*2 в степени -2. Пока всё в порядке, обе дроби конечные. Умножаем на 10: 0,25*10=2,5. Округляем: ((int)2.5)=2. Старшая цифра получена, это 2. То есть промежуточный результат перевода в десятичную 0,2. Теперь нам надо вычислить 0,25-0,2, чтоб дальше переводить уже эту разность. Но 0,2 – это 1/5, двоичное представление одной пятой БЕСКОНЕЧНО. И вместо 0,25 даже при правильной записи в память легко можно вывести 0,24999999999999...

Comment: Да, 0,25 вполне так выводится с двумя знаками. Но этом другое число может иметь экранное представление тоже 0,25, при этом двоичное x==y вернёт false, а любое явное указание точности – это уже частный случай.

Comment: @ТарасАтавин, так и в чём сомнения? Ну, "БЕСКОНЕЧНО" и в чём проблема? При работе с `double` или `float` у нас это на каждом шаге же. Если поставить задачу для данного значения `double` найти десятичное представление с наименьшим количеством знаков такое, что оно отличается от данного не более чем на Δ, она будет иметь решение? Так и да, будет иметь вполне корректное решение.

Comment: В частном значении Δ же.

Comment: Хм, конечно, поскольку это алгоритм, то каждая реализация алгоритма для конкретных аргументов окажется частным случаем. Но сама задача имеет решение для любого наперёд не заданного Δ (которая, известна или может быть получена для любого числа с плавающей точкой), и, обычно, это называют «решение в общем виде».

Comment: Решение есть, но оно частное: переводить не в двоичной системе, а в двоично-десятичной. Но надо опираться на конкретные внутренности формата.

Answer (score 2):

Из-за проблем с числами с плавающей точкой, предложил бы вам решить это с помощью строк.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string num;
    cin >> num;

    int position = num.find(".");
    string afterDot = num.substr(position + 1);

    cout << afterDot.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о числах с плавающей запятой, то надо точно сформулировать, что понимать "под количеством знаков после запятой". А именно:

1. 0.00125, 1.25e+10, 12.5 - все имеют три значащие цифры или как-то иначе?
2. Как относится к ошибкам округления?

Примеры возможных представлений в типе `double`:

- 0.86 ≈ 0.85999999999999998;
- 0.87 ≈ 0.86999999999999999;
- 0.88 ≈ 0.88000000000000000;
- 0.89 ≈ 0.89000000000000001;

Вариант кода для ответов "да, все имеют три значащие цифры" и "как обычно, ошибки округления не учитывать":

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  // И это, ей Богу, клянусь! Последний раз,
                    // когда я пишу обращение к этому кривому пылесосу!
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename F>
unsigned num_digits(F x, 
            unsigned digits10 = numeric_limits<F>::digits10) {
    auto max_digits10 = numeric_limits<F>::max_digits10;
    ostringstream ss;

    ss << std::scientific << setprecision(max_digits10) << x << "\n.\n";

    auto s = ss.str();
    auto dpos = s.find("."); // TODO: std::numpunct<CharT>::decimal_point
    auto sad = s.substr(dpos, max_digits10);
    auto l = digits10;
    auto d = sad[l];

    if(d == '0' || d == '9') {
        while(0 < l && d == sad[l]) {
            --l;
        }
    }

    return l + 1;
}

typedef double ftype;

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    int p;

    if(ac <= 1 || 0 >= (p = atoi(av[1]))) {
        p = 1;
    }

    int n = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        n *= 10;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        auto f = i/(ftype)n;
        auto nd = num_digits(f);
    
        assert(nd <= n);
        cout << f << " - " << nd << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кажется, вы копаете глубже, чем автору нужно. *"Пример: ввёл число 1.324234. Получил: 6 знаков после запятой. Ввёл 1.1"* - разумно предположить, что он вводит просто текст в инпут.

Comment: @Kromster, ну, уж что выкопано, то выкопано, не закапывать же обратно.